# run scripts in a page loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can I run a script in a page loaded by ajax?

The fact that all script code is being removed when you use jquery.load is really annoying. I am trying to use AJAX so I do not need to reload the entire page.

Script, currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a, #nav-top li a, #nav-left li a, #nav-right li a').not('.scroll').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)  
    }                                           
});



$('#nav li a, #nav-top li a, #nav-left li a, #nav-right li a').not('.scroll').click(function(){  

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content>*';  // there must be a blank space in ' #content>*'
    $('#content').hide(888,loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn(888);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(888,hideLoader());  
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(888);
    }

    return false;

});

});
```

Working demo example page here:

http://www.ideagasms.net/index2
(Just click the 'home' and 'about' links to see it in action.)

I have all of my jquery in three files that are minified; they include things like php/jquery shopping cart, lazyload, lightbox, and more. I'd like all three of my main js files to "stay alive" so that, when I add, for example, an 'add to cart' button or img.lazyload to the #content div, those things will still function.

I've heard that the livequery plugin is a decent solution, but it's way over my head, and to me it seems like possible overkill.

There must be a way to modify the above script to include one.min.js two.min.js and three.min.js and thus "retrigger" them so they stay active.

If this question is a big deal I'm willing to hire whoever can figure this out. I can then re-post the solutions here. (This question I'm asking has been asked all over the place, including the main nettuts page where I got the above "load in and animate content using jquery" script, and the solution still evades most people, although some have managed to fix this, I can't figure out how to implement their solutions. Whoever can resolve this once and for all will be helping hundreds of frustrated people in one shot. You build a whole new site using a nettuts tutorial, only to find out a week into the job that it's no good for loading content that has associated scripts... it's damn frustrating.)

Comment: I think what you are really asking is - how come when I load content via AJAX, the event handlers that I bound on pageReady don't work? This has indeed been asked many times. Take a look at jQuery's `on` method. This allows you to monitor a higher level node (body for instance would catch everything) for clicks of subnodes. Alternatively you can just rebind your event handlers after you load new content.

Comment: Thanks, can you modify the above script using .on or whatever, and repost it here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (shot in the dark).

```
$('body').on('click', '#nav li a, #nav-top li a, #nav-left li a, #nav-right li a', function() {
    if (this.hasClass('scroll')) { return; }

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content>*'; // there must be a blank space in ' #content>*'
    $('#content').hide(888, loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn(888);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0, $(this).attr('href').length - 4);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
    }

    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(888, hideLoader());
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(888);
    }

    return false;

});​
```

Comment: The above re-write works (i.e., it keeps all my jquery scripts alive) BUT unfortunately it also forces a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if your page is well formed, you don't need to retrieve JS code from Ajax call.
Ajax call are used to return data (such as **JSON**, **XML**, or other type of data or a piece of **HTML** for a specific area).

You should put your JS script in the first loaded page.

If you really need to load some script, you can create new script node and put them on the head of the DOM document (Assuming your Ajax response data containing the path to the good JS script to load).